# Is there any way to temporarily accept website certificate that isn't trusted in Safari/High Sierra?

Tags: safari, security, keychain

Is there any way to temporarily allow Safari to load a site with an untrusted website certificate in Safari/High Sierra?

This was possible in Sierra. I marked several roots Untrusted due to their bad behavior in issuing certificates. At one time I think there was an option in KeyChain Viewer to "Ask User", but that was depreciated.

A similar question was answered here ([How do I bypass "this connection is not private" warnings in safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301098/how-do-i-bypass-this-connection-is-not-private-warnings-in-safari)), but the answer is not correct for High Sierra: there is no longer an option "visit the site".