# Missing “visit this website” bypass to “this connection is not private” warnings in Safari

Tags: macos, safari

Attempting to follow the instructions in the previous question [How do I bypass "this connection is not private" warnings in safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301098/how-do-i-bypass-this-connection-is-not-private-warnings-in-safari) shows that the "Show Details" → "visit this website" link is not there anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can still open the page in a private window.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info (e.g. how to use *private mode*) as many users visiting the site will be unaware of how to do this. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here. All the best! :)

Comment: Using a private window still does not work. Any other ideas?